# Java: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when searching for an Integer value in an Array

Tags: java

If i am looking for a certain value (needle) in an arrary and the value doens't exit in this array I am getting an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. (see Code below)
If the value exists in the array it works just fine.

It seems I am sitting already to long in front of my computer and i am already to blind to see the mistake, any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int i = 0;
   int[] array;
   array = new int[5];
   int needle = 20; 
   boolean inarray;


   array[0] = 4;
   array[1] = 7;
   array[2] = 13;
   array[3] = 29;
   array[4] = 5;

    while (i <= array.length && needle != array[i]){
        i++;
    }
    inarray = !(i > array.length);
    System.out.println("value in array: " + inarray);

}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:33)
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Just change it to i < array.length.

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to get into the habit of declaring variables at the point of first use, rather than all of them at the top of the method - and initialize at the point of declaration, e.g. `int[] array = new int[5];` or better yet `int[] array = { 4, 7, 13, 29, 5 };`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are zero based (Java ain't Fortran you know): `array[0]` *is* valid for an non-zero length array.

Change the fist part of your stopping condition to `i < array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

array.length is 5 so when you are trying to get array[5] you get error. Just change

```
i <= array.length
```

to

```
i < array.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line piece of code.

```
while (i <= array.length && needle != array[i]){
    i++;
}
```

As you have in your example, the first position of your array is the position 0 and the last is position 4. when you do `array.length` it returns 5. So your `i <= array.length` will evaluate to true when `i=5`, and will give you the exception you're having evaluationg `array[i]`, because `array[5]` does not exist.

Instead of `i <= array.length` change your condition to `i < array.length`.

Comment: Probably you can remove from the answer the line of code that populates the array, this will make your answer clearer ;)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
i <= array.length
```

to

```
i < array.length
```

or

```
i <= (array.length-1)
```

Index starts from 0 onward till length-1